# IOS: fill a NSArray with UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uiimageview

In my project I created 30 small UIImageView where inside I put a different background. This  is my group of UIImageView without background

[image]

and this is the group of UIImageView with different background:

[image]

I put these group of UImageView inside a UITableViewCell and I use them to define a timeline, but it's not important.
I declared in .h these UIImageView but now I must insert theme in an NSArray, or NSMutableArray? Because in my code (depending on the case) I must set different background for each UIImageView. How can I organize them in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would suggest drawing your timeline view using a single UIView, dynamically creating and storing views in an array is simple:

```
NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray array];

NSUInteger viewCount = 30;
NSUInteger index;

for (index = 0; index < viewCount; index++) {
   UIImageView *newView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage] autorelease];

   [newView setFrame:CGRectMake(index * width, 0.0, width, height);

   [[self someView] addSubview:newView];
   [views addObject:newView];
}
```

Remember to retain or copy `views` at some point.

Then, to modify a view:

```
[[views objectAtIndex:8] setImage:anotherImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to put them all in an array. What you actually want to do is assign 'tags' to each view. Then, you can use `-[UIView viewWithTag:(int)];` to get a pointer to the image view you want to 'talk' to at the time. Keep in mind not to use negative numbers or 0 when tagging your views.